# Is there any (major) difference between the Galaxy Note 3 on different US carriers?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3

I am currently a loyal Verizon customer, and have been pretty much forever.
My current phone is a Galaxy Nexus, and my previous phone was a Droid, and the carrier has been fairly hands-off with these "stock" Android models.

I'm currently out of contract, so I have the ability to freely/easily switch carriers if need be.
I really like Verizon's coverage, but might be willing to jump ship for various reasons.
(Carrier decision is really a separate question)

I'm currently interested in the Galaxy Note 3. However, I'm concerned about what modifications Verizon may have made to their version of this model.
The main reason for my concern is this list of differences about the previous model, the Note 2: http://engadget.com/2012/12/07/dnp-samsung-galaxy-note-ii-verizon-review/
What especially concerns me is things that were *removed* and *hardware* differences, such as the Verizon model of the Note 2 missing the wireless charging contacts, but on principle I am also concerned about firmware and software differences (other than the necessary CDMA chip, of course, and I can live with additional Verizon branding and bloatware).

I have asked this question in a variety of forums, including asking Verizon and Samsung directly, but haven't gotten a straight answer. I'm hoping that "no news is good news" and I would really like to dive in and take this model. But if there are any differences, I'd like to know them.
I just want to make sure I am getting the features as-advertised by Samsung.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you need to just keep reading reviews. [This one](http://androidcommunity.com/verizon-galaxy-note-3-hands-on-20131015/), for instance, says that the only difference between the Verizon version and other versions is the chip for the network and, of course, the carrier-branded apps.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is exactly the sort of review I was looking for to confirm. I'd give you a "best answer" if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Self-answering update from OP:**
I have now owned a Verizon Galaxy Note 3 for about 6 months and there are no significant differences between this and another carrier's model.
It even has an official upgrade path to KitKat at this point (although not yet OTA at the time I posted this answer).

http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: ...and as of today, KitKat is going OTA.

Answer (score 2):

I found good info on the hardware specs here:
http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Samsung-Galaxy-Note-3_id7984
I'd compare that to any stats verizon releases.
Word on the street is it will be both CDMA and GSM, so I wouldn't be surprised if there are no differences.
My reading:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2469047

Comment: I'm really hoping for something as in-depth an analysis as the engadget article about the II. Since there hasn't been anything on the web about it in 5 days -- an eternity in internet-negative-comment time -- I'm currently assuming they didn't change as much this time around.

Answer (score 0):

As [underscorenorm mentions](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/55136/7112), it is your responsibility to ensure that the specs published by Verizon either match those posted by Samsung, or that the differences are acceptable to you. However, if the Note 3 is advertised with a particular feature and you purchase a Note 3 then it is reasonable for you to expect that feature.

Therefore, I would **highly recommend** that you contact Verizon **in writing** with your question and your concern. Doing this will let them know that their **spending money to modify the device** is actually **costing them potential customers**. A few letters like that might convince the company to keep their hands off the device.

*Posting as an answer, not a comment, due to recommending a different course of action than does underscorenorm.*

Comment: OP here. While I never set a "best answer" back in October because I felt Al E's comment was better than underscorenorm's answer, I have owned my Note 3 for several months now and there are no significant carrier differences. Sorry I never followed up, but my concerns were assuaged.

Comment: Great, thanks for mentioning it. I suggest that you answer your own question **with that information included** and accept it. The purpose of "best answer" is to inform _those who come after us_ of the **best answer**. The reward to the answerer is just gravy.